# How to identify align points in a gather environment

Tags: align, lyx, environments, gather

I am using Lyx. I have created a set of equations in a gather environment. Now I think it would be better if I get the equal signs aligned. I don't like to reconstruct my equations again in an align environment, it will be a useless effort.

Comment: `gather` is specifically for equations with no alignment specified. Change your `gather` to `align` and then place `&` before the `=`

Comment: why do you say this would be useless effort, surely changing `gather` to `align` is a trivial edit?

Comment: @David Carlisle, how can I easily switch from the gather to align away from using codes, the code in Lyx is uneditable.

Comment: I have no idea at all about lyx sorry but surely any editor worth the name "editor" could change one word to another??? But in any case that is what you need to do.

Comment: How did you get `gather` in LyX in the first place? Surely there must be some drop menu for you to choose the AMS environments, including `gather` and `align`.

Comment: @Ruixi Zhang, yes all the options are there. What I am searching for is  the following: once you have chosen an environment and written down your equations, is there any magical option with just one click to let you change your environment?

Comment: Continued: For now, I have created an align environment above the gather and started to cut and past my equations one by one.